# Insert statement not working. transfer from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Pretty new to PHP and MySQL.

I have created an insert statement in my php script, to transfer a row of data from one table to the next for certain fields. Only thing is, it doesn't seem to be working?

Can anybody see where the issue is?

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Instruction"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $Reference=$_REQUEST['Reference'];
 $Forename=$_REQUEST['Forename'];
     $surname=$_REQUEST['surname'];
 $DOB=$_REQUEST['DOB'];
 $Mobile=$_REQUEST['Mobile'];
 $Home=$_REQUEST['Home'];
 $Address=$_REQUEST['Address'];
 $Postcode=$_REQUEST['Postcode1'];
 $Email=$_REQUEST['Email'];
 $Accident=$_REQUEST['Accident'];
 $Details=$_REQUEST['Details'];


//semi colon removed  
$sql="INSERT INTO Triage (Reference,Forename,surname,D.O.B,Mobile Number,Home Number,Address,Postcode1,Email,Accident,Details)
 VALUES('.$Reference.','.$Forename.','.$surname.','.$DOB.','.$Mobile.','.$Home.','.$Address.','.$Postcode1.','.$Email.','.$Accident.','.$Details.')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);


 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";


 ?>
```

Comment: try echo $sql; and tell us what the output is, at the moment, the problem is very unclear

Comment: here is the out put, not all the data is being inserted... INSERT INTO Triage ('Reference','Forename','surname','D.O.B','Mobile Number','Home Number','Address','Postcode1','Email','Accident','Details') VALUES ('.88888.','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..')

Comment: Try running that string through PHPMyAdmin(or another tool) and see what error it gives

Comment: is it because I have specified the second table?

Comment: still doesn't work but is it only getting the reference field from the ajax?... http://****/refertotriage.php?Reference=88888

Comment: Have you read my last comment?

Comment: yes sorry, it doesn't give an error just inserts the names which are in the code. I think have figured it out but not sure how to do it?... I have an ajax but how does my code know how to use the reference in the ajax to move the certain fields into the other table?... so do I need to add some code to say using the reference in the ajax move these fields (a,b,c,) from table 1 into table2 (a,b,c)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'I have an ajax', ajax is a javascript scripting technique.

Comment: im not too sure myself either but its when I want to select a row from a table and use the data from that row... e.g. http://****/refertotriage.php?Reference=88888 ... using row with a reference of 888888... not sure what it is called then sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have column names like Mobile Numbe etc, you need to use `` for them also the concatenation does not look correct you should have something as

```
sql="INSERT INTO 
     Triage 
     (
       Reference, 
       Forename,
       surname,
       `D.O.B`,
       `Mobile Number`,
       `Home Number`,
       Address,
       Postcode1,
       Email,
       Accident,
       Details
      )
     VALUES
  (
    '".$Reference."',
    '".$Forename."',
    '".$surname."',
    '".$DOB."',
    '".$Mobile."',
    '".$Home."',
    '".$Address."',
    '".$Postcode1."',
    '".$Email."',
    '".$Accident."',
    '".$Details."'
 )";
```

In addition you should use mysql_real_escape_string() for all the request data something as

```
$Reference=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Reference']);
```

and so on for others

Comment: I have changed that and the script still doesn't work but I should of still put those in aswell. any idea why its not working?

Comment: use mysql_error() after the insert query it will tell u whats happening.

Comment: I have tried that but when using the browser I just get page cannot be displayed? should I removed sections out to see which part it fails on?

Comment: Yes page can not be displayed is a weird issue you need to debug by removing line by line or set error display to all on the page.

Comment: here is the out put, not all the data is being inserted... INSERT INTO Triage ('Reference','Forename','surname','D.O.B','Mobile Number','Home Number','Address','Postcode1','Email','Accident','Details') VALUES ('.88888.','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..','..')

Comment: oh almost everything is going as NULL, 'Reference' in the col name is not correct it should have backticks check my answer you are using single quote

Comment: I have copied your answer but still no luck, is it because I haven't specified the second table?

Comment: Make sure what ever you are entering is for that table. Check the fields on the table and then see on query. You can  not have columns of other table in a query which is adding to another table.

Comment: still doesn't work but is it only getting the reference field from the ajax?... http://****/refertotriage.php?Reference=88888

Comment: what happens if you execute the query on mysql directly any error u get ?

Comment: I thinki have figured it out but not sure how to do it?... I have an ajax but how does my code know how to use the reference in the ajax to move the certain fields into the other table?... so do I need to add some code to say using the reference in the ajax move these fields (a,b,c,) from table 1 into table2 (a,b,c)?